# What's the exact sequence of events for an Embrace in Vampire: the Requiem?

Tags: chronicles-of-darkness-1e, vampire-the-requiem

I've been digging around in the Requiem book and so far it looks like there's no single entry explaining how the Embrace works. The bit about draining and feeding vitae is in one part of the book, the bit about spending a willpower dot is in another, and I can't for the life of me find where it says how much vitae a newly-embraced vampire has in their system. Can anyone either give me a bullet-point run-down of the process or point me to the page number I've apparently overlooked?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Things are, indeed, a little scattered in the **Requiem** core book, a consequence of being one of the first books to hit shelves for the nWoD. A later book, called simply **The Blood**, organizes things better.

To answer your question: The prospective sire kills, and probably exsanguinates, the prospective childe. At the moment of death — the "right" moment for dramatic purposes — the Sire feeds the childe a point of Vitae and burns a dot of *permanent* Willpower to empower the magic that causes the victim to rise as a vampire. The point of vitae spent engenders the Blood Sympathy and a first-rank Viniculum.

The usual answer to "how much blood is in a newly created vampire?" is "none" or "however much of his sire's blood is expended in the creation."